# Dynamic content for webpage

Tags: artificial-intelligence

a couple weeks ago, I had that idea of creating a "smart content element" for my CMS. The idea behind that is, based on the visited pages of a visitor (saved eg. in a cookie), the visitor gets dynamic content.

Eg. I visit some product pages and after 2 pages, the cms shows on another product page with normal content and one dynamic content element, based on suggested content.

Of cource the user flow behind that needs to be really good and approved.

Is that some how possible, or my does something like that exist, maybe wie some kind of AI?

Thx

Comment: I would know more about that as well.